# return a Map<key, value> using Group by clause in HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, group-by, hashmap

I want to write a native query for hibernate which will group all the record for event id and return a map(groupByColumn -> entity).

Like `Map<Integer, List<StaffingTbl>>` where key is some column on which I use Group By clause, and value is the list of grouped Entity.

I am trying something like this, which doesn't work

```
SELECT new Map(e.id, s) FROM staffing_tbl s 
INNER JOIN user_tbl u on u.id = s.userId
INNER JOIN event_tbl e on u.eventId = e.id 
WHERE e.id IN (:ids) 
GROUP BY e.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't write a native query and use the HQL feature `new map`. You will have to do the grouping yourself, but that should be easy with the Java 8 Stream API. Something like this:

```
session.createNativeQuery("...", Object[].class)
  .addScalar("id")
  .addEntity(StaffingTbl.class)
  .getResultList()
  .stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    array -> (Integer) array[0], 
    Collectors.mapping((StaffingTbl) array[1], Collectors.toList())
))
```